# Error: Unable to import binding 'CustomBinding_IWSTrustFeb2005Async' from namespace

Tags: web-services, wsdl, certificate, ws-security

Using ASP.NET  / Visual Studio 2005 / 2012:

I have a .wsdl file from service provider, which I need to test.
I ran `wsdl.exe myfile.wsdl` from Vs command promopt but I get this error:

```
Error: Unable to import binding 'CustomBinding_IWSTrustFeb2005Async' from namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/securitytokenservice'.
- Unable to import operation 'TrustFeb2005IssueAsync'.
- The element 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust:RequestSecurityToken' is missing.
```

I also tried to Add Web Reference from VS 2005 and VS 2012 but that is also throwing weird error.

```
 - The WSDL document contains links that could not be resolved.
  - There was an error downloading 'file:///C:/Users/abcd12/Documents/Visual Studio 2005/MyWebserviceTest/mex.xsd'.
```

Any idea what's wrong or where should I start looking into?

**Update:** The Visual Studio error adding reference is gone once I removed the entry to type import referencing mex.xsd.
But now VS is also giving the same error as command prompt.

**Update:** Looks like the wsdl is corrupted. Waiting from the provider to give me updated wsdl.

I will update here if I need any further help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some .xsd files imported in the wsdl weren't provided to me. Once I got those files, all went fine.